# Undefined return of onChange event for mapped options for select input

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I have an array of objects as a state:

```
users: [
    {
      label: "user 1",
      value: "user_1"
    },
    {
      label: "user 2",
      value: "user_2"
    },
  ]
```

and I have a select input as follows:

```
<Input type="select" name="user" id="user" value={this.state.userValue} onChange={this.handleChange}>
   <option value="">-----</option>
   { this.state.users.map((user, index)=>
     <option value={user.value} key={index}>{user.label}</option>
   )}
</Input>
```

Now the issue comes with the event handler as in the function `handleChange`, the event object is a `SyntheticEvent`. I found similar problems with radio inputs and dropdown lists and the typical solution is to pass a second attribute to account for the data (e.g. `handleChange = (e, data) => { ...` yet `data` is returned as undefined as well when I tried to console log it!

update 1: I tried e.persist() and the return is undefined.
the handle function is basically as follows:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  console.log(e.persist())
  // this.setState({
  //     userValue: e.target.value
  // }
  // );
};
```

the state change is commented just to prevent the error when the return event is undefined.

update 2: sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-sound-3u7xk

Comment: in the handle change function, try adding e.persist() and second line check whether you are getting the value e.target.value ?

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS I tried that but the return is undefined =(

Comment: Is this Input component is a custom or any library one can you add the Input Component code also

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS this is from reactstrap. It doesn't matter, tried changing the tag to a normal select element, yet the issue is still there.

Comment: It's wierd let me try it give me some time

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS Sure, take your time =) .. this is the sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-sound-3u7xk

Comment: Check this i am able to get the value https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-bhaskara-sd1p0 let me know did this worked for you